# Vagrant and PHP "mkdir"

Tags: php, vagrant, file-permissions, mkdir

If having some problems with PHPs `mkdir` function when in a Vagrant box.

What happens is the following, I create a folder:

```
mkdir('path/to/directory', 0775, true);
```

This succesfully creates the folder with the following permissions on my **Vagrant box**:

```
drwxrwxr-x 1 www-data vagrant directory
```

and the following on my **local machine**:

```
drwxr-xr-x  3 root staff directory
```

On my local machine however (where I'm actually going to do stuff with the file) I can't edit the files within the folder and PHPStorm shows a lock at the directory.

When I do something like `file_put_contents()` to create a file and chmod that file to 0664 or 0775  I **can** edit it.

Any help would be appreciated.

**I already tried an extra `chmod` on the directory, didn't work.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out my Vagrant box was build with sudo, hence the directory was from root instead of my own user.